# How to redirect pages using get() and res.sendFile() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is just not redirecting to the page!

I put this in the index.html:

```
$.get( "/loginPage", function( data ) {});
```

The index.html page basically checks if user is logged in. If it is, then it redirects to lobbyPage.
The backend code:

```
app.get('/loginPage', function(req,res){
console.log("Hello");
sess=req.session;
if(sess.username!=undefined)
{
    res.redirect('/lobby');
}
else
{
    console.log("Not logged in!");

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/loginPage.html'); //This isn't working!
}

});
```

The res.sendFile just wouldn't send the loginPage! The console is printing "Hello" and "Not logged in!" messages so I think everything else is working fine.

Some relevant information:

I have put the loginPage.html  in both, the public directory as well as the directory before it.
And I've used this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Also, I'm running it on Windows. Can the backslash/forwardslash cause a problem because of this?

Comment: 1. Check the path and file name.                                                                2. The app.js i.e) the file that contains the response and the public directory should be in the same directory.

Comment: 1. The path and file names are correct.
2. Yes, the server.js, lobby.html and public directory are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

`$.get( "/loginPage", function( data ) {});`

to:

`window.location = '/loginPage'`

All the server-side code there works, the problem is that the client isn't doing anything with the ajax result once it has it.  By simply pointing the browser window at that url, it will either follow any redirects or render the resulting payload.